# Space between dash and inequality in latex

Tags: latex

I want to write `"->"` in Latex but when i use

```
\begin{math}
->
\end{math}
```

syntax the result is `"- >"`. How to remove this inner space?

Comment: Can you use `\rightarrow` instead?

Comment: no i have to use - combined with > exactly

Comment: Can you give a bit more background information about the context you want to use this? Also please make a [mre]

Comment: i need to use "->" exactly because the purpose is not to use an arrow but to show how exactly file data for my program should look like

Comment: In this case math is the total thing to use. Have a look at the `listings` package